# Can't launch PhpStorm from unity only from a terminal

Tags: unity, software-installation, launcher

I have a program, PhpStorm, that i can launch from anywhere if i use the terminal, if i try to do from unity interface nothing happens.

I have exported the `<program_name>/bin` path to `PATH` environment, someone can help me?

Thanks

I'm with ubuntu 14.04

Comment: what's the program? From where are how did you install it?

Comment: The program is PhpStorm, the folder is in opt

Comment: where is `PhpStorm.sh` located? try `locate PhpStorm.sh`

Comment: PhpStorm.sh path is:  /opt/PhpStorm-<numer_version>/bin

Comment: did you run `PhpStorm.sh`? Are there any erros?

Comment: No errors from terminal

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove desktop shortcut for PhpStorm:
   `rm ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop`
2. Run PhpStorm from console and from its menu, choose `Tools -> Create Desktop Entry`
3. Log out from your ubuntu session
4. Log in to new session
5. Unity Launcher will be correct now and will work

This has to be done each upgrade since each PhpStorm version is usually unpacked to folder named like `PhpStorm-143.1184.87` and that changes with every version, but the desktop entry update is not part of the PhpStorm update (since PhpStorm update usually means just unpacking new release to another folder)

Another way of doing this is of course pointing this desktop link to `/usr/local/bin/phpstorm`, but then again you still have to use `Tools -> Create Command Line Launcher` with every update (which you WILL do if you are console user, anyways ;) )